# Foreach repite valor

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla en la base de datos de mi localhost que se llama `usuarios`. Esa tabla tiene lo siguiente:

```
    pk | login    |   nombre     | email              | control
   =============================================================
    1    usuario1   Usuario     usuario1@usuario.com       0
    2    usuario2   Usuario     usuario2@usuario.com       0
    3    usuario3   Usuario     usuario3@usuario.com       1
```

Estoy intentado que me muestre el `email` de los dos usuarios que tienen `control=0`, pero lo que me ocurre es que me muestra el `email` de `usuario1` dos veces. ¿Alguna ayuda? Les dejo mi código:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die('Error al conectar'. mysqli_errno($link));;

  mysqli_select_db($link, "prueba");

  $result = mysqli_query($link, "select email from usuarios where control = 0");

  $extraido= mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  foreach($extraido as $email){
    echo "".$email."</br>";
  }
```

El resultado que me devuelve es:

```
usuario1@usuario.com
usuario1@usuario.com
```

El que deseo es:

```
usuario1@usuario.com
usuario2@usuario.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta línea `$extraido= mysqli_fetch_array($result);`, si haces un `var_dump` seguramente tendra dos valores; `$extraido[0]="usuario1@usuario.com"`y `$extraido["email"]="usuario1@usuario.com"`por lo que al hacer el foreach te esta imprimiendo dos veces usuario1.

Prueba con:

```
while ($extraido= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         echo "".$extraido["email"]."</br>";
    }
```

Comment: Me ha sido de gran ayuda! Gracias!